# permutation polynomial

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

If we have $\operatorname{GF}(4)$ as an extension field, we can define a permutation polynomial of $\operatorname{GF}(4)$ like $L(x)$, a linearized polynomial, of the followinf form:
$L(x)= \sum\limits_{s=0}^{r-1} a_s x^{q^s} $
Is it possible to get more details for $\operatorname{GF}(4)$ and $\operatorname{GF}(2)$. I want to know more about Betti-Mathieu group. What are the permutation polynomials of $\operatorname{GF}(4)$ over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$? According to mentioned group the set of $L(x)$ is isomorph to $\operatorname{GL}(2,2)$ in my case. Actually I need to know more about this notion with more practical examples.
How many permutation polynomial there exist for $\operatorname{GF}(4)$ over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$?

Comment: What is a permutation polynomial over $GF(2)$? One with coefficients in $GF(2)$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial. Please consider the part of finite fields.

Comment: the basis of GF(4) as a vector space over GF(2) is for instance 1 and a. So permutation polynomial is x+x^2? right?

Comment: $x+x^2$ is not a permutation, because it only takes on two values with $x$ ranging over $GF(4)$.

Comment: My copy of Lidl&Niederreiter is in my office, so cannot check, but looks like you allow coefficients from the bigger field. Then consider the following: any permutation of the three non-zero elements of $GF(4)$ is a linear mapping (the sum of any two is the third). Also any mapping from $GF(4)$ to itself is a polynomial by Lagrange interpolation. Put these together.

Comment: Can we correspond a matrix for permutation polynomials? The matrix representation of GF(4) is the set including three matrices: I,A,I+A . How is the matrix representation of permutation polynomial as a linear map?